# SharePoint Email Alert when particular user sends an email

Tags: 2010, email, alert

I'm not sure if this question has been asked, but I was wondering is there a way to send an email alert to a user when an email is sent from a certain user in SharePoint 2010. I know you can send various alerts when documents are accessed, files are opened, etc. I was wondering about this feature in particular though.

**I.E.** If ***User A*** wants to know when ***User B*** sends email to the site collections SharePoint email address (location@dev.portal.company.net)

- Cheers

Comment: Are you referring to when UserB sends an email to an email-enabled list in SharePoint?

Comment: Yes, this is what I am referring to. More so, a Document Library where things are actually stored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the email being sent causes [one of the many events available in SharePoint](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brianwilson/archive/2007/03/05/part-1-event-handlers-everything-you-need-to-know-about-microsoft-office-sharepoint-portal-server-moss-event-handlers.aspx) to fire you can very easily create custom event receivers to react on it.

Answer (score 0):

Given the very specific nature of your request, I'd start with trying to create a workflow in SharePoint Designer that would generate the email under the conditions you list.  Failing that, you would have to go with a custom eventReceiver as detailed in the link mentioned by tylerrrr07

Comment: By creating a workflow, will this be triggered when a particular person has sent an email from that particular address as stated above in my question? Didn't know if it would be initiated on the fly...